# Has the firebase link been removed?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Long time ago I did an app on eclipse that connected to my firebase account, it used this line of code to connect to it:

```
 Firebase authnewuser = new Firebase("https://xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com");
```

Now, following the tutorials in Android studio itself, I can't see such "connection string", it asked me to connect to it in the tutorials, which opened a new web browser and successfully logged in, but how does the app in Android studio knows that it suppose to connect to that account?
Is it stored somewhere in the code?
All the samples I am seeing don't reference my account's link

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the legacy firebase link and dashboard. If you had logged into your dashboard early this year, You would have seen their warning that apps should be migrated to the new platform. Firebase has really evolved from what it used to be, Its now a full blown cloud platform with Some cool features

Comment: So how do you connect to your firebase account?

Comment: Just login to the firebase legacy console https://www.firebase.com/login/ , click on your old project and it will prompt you to move your project to the new console. Just click on Continue to proceed